# RDD operation to sort values in pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a file format as follow,

```
0, Alpha,-3.9, 4, 2001-02-01, 5, 20
0, Beta,-3.8, 3, 2002-02-01, 6, 21
1, Gamma,-3.7, 8, 2003-02-01, 7, 22
0, Alpha,-3.5, 4, 2004-02-01, 8, 23
0, Alpha,-3.9, 4, 2005-02-01, 8, 27
```

I want to sort distinct `1st elements` in each line by `3rd elements` using rdd operation. I prefer to get the following output,

```
(Beta, 3)
(Alpha, 4)
(Gamma, 8)
```

This is what I have done at the moment,

```
rdd = sc.textFile(myDataset)
list_ = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda e : e[1]).distinct().collect() 
new_ = list_.sortBy(lambda e : e[2])
```

But I could not sort as I wanted. Could anyone tell how to do this only rdd based operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rdd = sc.textFile(myDataset)` is correct.

```
list_ = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda e : e[1]).distinct().collect() 
new_ = list_.sortBy(lambda e : e[2]) # e[2] does not exist.
```

You already called collect on `list_`, so it is no longer an RDD. Then you have proceeded to call `sortBy` on it, so it won't work. Perhaps you made this mistake while posting.
The main issue is the map operation. You need to create a [pairWiseRdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066106/difference-and-use-cases-of-rdd-and-pair-rdd), but you have not created one. Hence, there is no `e[2]` to sort with. See below.

```
>>> rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda e : e[1]).collect()
[' Alpha', ' Beta', ' Gamma', ' Alpha', ' Alpha']
```

The above will not have the value you need to use the `distinct()`
Instead, you need to do this

```
>>> list_ = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda e : (e[1],e[3]))
>>> list_.collect()
[(' Alpha', ' 4'),
 (' Beta', ' 3'),
 (' Gamma', ' 8'),
 (' Alpha', ' 4'),
 (' Alpha', ' 4')]
>>> distinct_rdd = list_.distinct() #making stuff distinct
>>> distinct_rdd.collect()
[(' Alpha', ' 4'), (' Beta', ' 3'), (' Gamma', ' 8')]
```

Now that we have made our pairWiseRdd, we can use the second value of every pair to sort it.

```
>>> sorted_rdd = distinct_rdd.sortBy( lambda x:x[1] )
>>> sorted_rdd.collect()
[(' Beta', ' 3'), (' Alpha', ' 4'), (' Gamma', ' 8')]
```